# Fixing Up an Animated Map

Tags: r, animation, maps, mapping, gganimate

I am putting the finishing touches on an animated map that I've been working on; below is the code in total:

```
library(ggmap)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)
register_google(key = )

file <- file.choose(new = TRUE)
origAddress <- read.csv(file name, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Minneapolis <- ggmap(get_googlemap(center = c(lon = -93.2638397, lat = 44.979969),
                                   zoom = 12, scale = 2,
                                   maptype = "terrain",
                                   color = "color"))

Properties <- data.frame(origAddress)
Properties

ghost_points_ini <- tibble(
  Closing.Date = as.numeric(2004/8),
  lon = 0, lat = 0)
ghost_points_fin <- tibble(
  Closing.Date = seq(as.numeric(2019/10),
                     as.numeric(2023/10),
                     by = "Year"),
  lon = 0, lat = 0)

Final_View <- Minneapolis + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = Year), data = Properties, size = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = 1),                
             data = ghost_points_ini, alpha = 0) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = 1),
             data = ghost_points_fin, alpha = 0) +
  transition_time(Year) +
  shadow_mark(past = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "title")

animate(Final_View, nframes = 500)
```

There are four things which are not coming out quite the way I was hoping, and I'm having trouble fixing them no matter how much tinkering and Googling I do, so any tips or pointing in the right direction would be helpful:

First, the map is being animated by year, so points are being plotted by the year the events happen.  However, I was hoping to have them simply appear, but something in my code is making them "move" from previous events instead of just appearing.  Is there something I need to add to my code to make it so that each point appears instead of traces?

Second, on the side of the map is the legend of colors, but above that is another legend that is just one white square that says "Size".  How can I get rid of this?

Third, at the moment I have a standard title that does not change as the map animates through the years, but I want to change this so that as each year passes, it changes the title to that year.  I thought that making my code:

```
labs(title = "{Year}")
```

would let me do this, but making the above my code seems to completely change my entire animation so that it doesn't even appear when I call it.  What about the above am I getting wrong?

And fourth, I attempted to include in the code some points before and after the "real" points would start being added, so that there was a pause, especially at the end.  For the pause at the end, I added the `ghost_points_fin` bit, but it doesn't make the map pause so that people will be able to see the final product for a few seconds.  Did I enter the `seq` part incorrectly?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: That's a lot of packages, no data and a google key. Are you sure revealing this key is OK? Could you make your example as minimal as possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by no data, since I do have data in the csv that I read in the code.  The animation also couldn't run without data, which it does, but that's not one of the issues I'm having.  Maybe you could clarify what you mean by that?  And thank you for the heads up on the key, I was just copy/pasting the code and forgot to delete it.

Comment: They mean theres no data in your example so we can't recreate the problem

Comment: By data do you mean the data that is in the spreadsheet? Just wondering because unfortunately I'm using internal data for the organization I work for, and I can't let certain info out.